# How do i prove that any two distinct irreducible monic polynomials in a field are relatively prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $P(x),Q(x)$ be distinct irreducible monic polynomials in $F$. Then how do i prove that $P(x),Q(x)$ are relatively prime?

I can prove this for an *infinite* field $F$ so that $P(x),Q(x)$ have a unique representation of polynomial respectively, but what if $F$ is finite?

Comment: What proof depends on the size of $F$?

Comment: @Math This is an exercise in my book, so I'm trying to prove it myself. There is no reference.

Comment: But you say "I can prove ...". What proof is that?

Comment: It would really be good if you included the proof that Math Gems is asking for in the post. We're kind of surprised you discovered a split in the finite/infinite case, and we are (or at least I am) thinking there might be a misconception. If there is some misconception in the proof we would like to help you clear it up. If you remain silent then you and I won't ever know if there was a problem :)

Comment: @rschwieb I was confused with the notion "$=$". Is there a special notation to distinguish "Equivalence in $F[X]$" from "equivalence in $F$"? I don't understand why one does not use some equivalence notation such as $\equiv$ for polynomials..

Comment: @rschwieb For example, $Z_2=\{0,1\}$ is a field if $1+1=0, 1+0=1, 0•0=0, 1•0=0$. Here, polynomials $f(x)=x^2 + x + 1$ and $g(x)=1$ are not equal polynomials, but they are equal functions.

Comment: @Katlus Oh! That's an interesting point :) We almost never consider polynomials equivalent as functions: the main way is equality of coefficients. I remember Isaacs going out of his way in his text to point out that polynomials can be equal as functions but not as polynomials. In short, I bet you will not come across polynomials being considered equal only as functions in practice. So I imagine you used an assumption of infiniteness to avoid the polynomials being equal as functions?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I made that assumption. Thank you!

Comment: @Katlus Thanks for elaborating. When teaching it is helpful to know which points may be tricky. The distinction between *formal* vs. *functional* polynomials is one weak spot in many algebra textbooks. You can find some [further discussion here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+polynomial+formal+functional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Write $A\sim B$ for $A$ is associate to $B$, i.e. $A = u B$ for some unit $u$. If $P$ is irreducible then the gcd $(P,Q)\neq 1\:\Rightarrow (P,Q)\sim P,\:$   So if $Q$ is also irreducible then $(P,Q)\sim Q,\:$ hence $P\sim Q.$ Therefore $P = Q$ (since both are monic), contra hypothesis.